# What causes history to be generated with CVS elements?

Tags: cvs, revision-history

I have six revisions of a SQL module re_sales.sql (creates an Informix SE table), but, when I run `cvs history -c re_sales.sql`, no history is displayed. Yet, I have other modules that when I run `cvs history -c`, a revision history prints.

I don't remember doing anything special when I `cvs add re_sales.sql` to the project.  I don't remember doing anything special when I added files whose history does display. I can get (`cvs update`)  each revision, but the modification dates are what I really want.

Where does CVS store its history and what causes CVS to create history, especially, when there are six revisions to the module?